# Why MongoDB getting higher memory usage?

Tags: mongodb, memory, python, cache

This is the sample **Python code** that I used to write data in **MongoDB database**. After every connection close, I restart the program and I noticed an **accumulation in memory count** in the ***Task Manager***. Anyone could guide me on this?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time as t

CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"

with MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING) as client:
    dbname = client['TESTING']
    collection_name = 'JUNE'
    collection = dbname[collection_name]
    

    for i in range(1000):
        now = datetime.now()
        real_time = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")
        body = {'Plant': 'MSIT', 'Packet': 'TESTINGS', 'TimeStamp': real_time}
        print(i)
        collection.insert_one(body)
    client.close()
```